# Google Cloud-Vision API Sample Code returns Resource exhausted error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-sdk

I'm running the following code from the cloud-vision API examples repo. I have followed the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries?refresh=1
to set up a service account and authentication, but I still can't successfully execute this function.

```
async function detectLabels() {
  // [START vision_label_detection]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

  // Creates a client
  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

  const fileName = './src/img/wakeupcat.jpg';

  // Performs label detection on the local file
  const [result] = await client.labelDetection(fileName);
  const labels = result.labelAnnotations;
  console.log('Labels:');
  labels.forEach(label => console.log(label.description));
  // [END vision_label_detection]
}

detectLabels();
```

This gives the following error:

Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service 'vision.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:6579173653'.

The wakupcat.jpg image I'm using is 14kb so it's not the size that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving is for the number of requests that you're making (and I think not the file size).

You may review your current quote usage for a specific project and API using the following URL:

[https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/vision-json.googleapis.com/quotas?folder=&organizationId=&project=[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/vision-json.googleapis.com/quotas?folder=&organizationId=&project=%5B%5BYOUR-PROJECT-ID%5D%5D)

You'll need to use the Project ID not the Project # (6579173653)

If as I suspect, you're exceeding your (daily? hourly?) quota, you may wait (until these reset) or apply for more:

[https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]&folder&organizationId&service=vision-json.googleapis.com](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=%5B%5BYOUR-PROJECT-ID%5D%5D&folder&organizationId&service=vision-json.googleapis.com)

You should be able to determine the Project ID using:

```sh
PROJECT_ID=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --filter="projectNumber~6579173653" \
  --format=value(projectId)") && echo ${PROJECT_ID}
```

**NB** It's unclear to me why this only works with `~` rather than `=`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do this step: export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"